# Не меняется свойство UIButton.titleLabel.text при загрузке страницы

Tags: swift, swift4

Вот такая дилемма - при загрузки контроллера идёт загрузка данных в массив, если массив не пустой, то кнопка нажимается и Черная, а наоборот - не нажимается и Серая. Так у меня массив не пустой и кнопка нажимается, при этом по умолчанию она Серая и загружается Серой! Как так то? Когда выхожу обратно в этот контроллер кнопка уже Чёрная!

class MenuVC: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var addBtn: UIButton!

```
@IBOutlet weak var repeatBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var lookBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func lookAction(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var pharaseBtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  fetchCoreDataObjects()
   lookBtn.titleLabel!.textColor = lookBtn.isEnabled  ?  #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)

}
```

var word:[Word] = []

```
func fetch(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Word>(entityName: "Word")

    do {
        word = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("Successfully fetched data")
        completion(true)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(false)
    }
}

func fetchCoreDataObjects() {
    self.fetch { (complete) in
        if complete {
            if word.count >= 1 {

                lookBtn.isEnabled = true
            } else {

                lookBtn.isEnabled = false
            }
```

Comment: Может вы проверяете массив не вовремя? Добавьте немного вашего кода в вопрос.

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      fetchCoreDataObjects()
       lookBtn.titleLabel!.textColor = lookBtn.isEnabled  ?  #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
  }

Comment: var word:[Word] = []
    
    func fetch(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Word>(entityName: "Word")

        do {
            word = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("Successfully fetched data")
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Could not fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }

Comment: func fetchCoreDataObjects() {
        self.fetch { (complete) in
            if complete {
                if word.count >= 1 {     lookBtn.isEnabled = true
                } else {   lookBtn.isEnabled = false
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не устанавливайте для `UIButton` напрямую title и titleColor.

> lookBtn.titleLabel!.textColor

Для этого есть специальные методы:

```
someButton.setTitle("someTitle", for: .normal)
someButton.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
```